# How can I use lambdas with methods in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have one method in C# that looks like this:

```
static Double Stirling(long n)
{
     return Math.Sqrt((2 * n + 1.0 / 3.0) * Math.PI) * Math.Pow(n, n) / Math.Exp(n);
}
```

My question is ... It is possible to use something like:

```
static Double Stirling(long n) => return Math.Sqrt((2 * n + 1.0 / 3.0) * Math.PI) * Math.Pow(n, n) / Math.Exp(n);
```

I want something more beautiful and more concise, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah! It was the 'return' keyword that gave me an error

Comment: And what makes you think using a lambda is going to be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use an expression bodied method.

```
static double Stirling(long n) => Math.Sqrt((2 * n + 1.0 / 3.0) * Math.PI) * Math.Pow(n, n) / Math.Exp(n);
```

This is only possible when the method executes a single statement, and in this case, we get rid of the `return` statement.

or you can use a `Func` delegate to represent a behaviour as such:

```
Func<long, double> func = (long n) => Math.Sqrt((2 * n + 1.0 / 3.0) * Math.PI) * Math.Pow(n, n) / Math.Exp(n);
```

and then call it like so:

```
double result = func(2);
```

it's important to note that the `=>` operator is used for both [expression bodied methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) (first example above) and [lambdas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) (second example above) but they're completely different beasts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this (just remove return)

```
static Double Stirling(long n) => Math.Sqrt((2 * n + 1.0 / 3.0) * Math.PI) * Math.Pow(n, n) / Math.Exp(n);
```

but this is expression body method from C# 6

see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#methods)